# unable to delete Nuget package from TFS - Package Management feed

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, package, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

C:>nuget.exe delete Package1 1.0.0.0 -Source https://test.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v2 -ApiKey VSTS

gives confirmation of package deleted

```
Package1  1.0.0.0 was deleted successfully.
```

However, when i refresh package management (TFS Web), the `'Package 1'` package is still show up in the Web interface. It shouldn't show here because it has been deleted. Right?

**Problem:** I can't further push package.

**Error:**

> Failed to process due to conflict.

Why so?

Comment: Currently, Package Management's web interface will continue to show you unlisted packages if you're an owner of the feed; it does this to show that the version number is reserved and can't be republished. We're considering adding a toggle in a future release that would hide deleted packages. If you'd like, you can enter a request on the Package Management UserVoice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/category/145266-package-management

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/get-started/nuget/remove) it says "Note: Unlisting is permanent. Once you unlist a version of a package, it cannot be re-listed.

```
You may not upload a package with the same name and version as the unlisted package."
```

Comment: While it's true I really hope they will add that feature in final release.